# How to cumulatively link values across rows and columns in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a Pandas DataFrame, where each row represents a link between two unique spots (source and target) within lineages. The lineages may only split into two, but they never merge:

```
   SOURCE_ID   TARGET_ID   Splitting_event 
0  1           68          False
1  68          72          False 
2  72          75          False 
3  75          81          True 
4  75          78          True 
5  78          557         False 
6  81          85          False 
7  85          88          True 
8  85          91          True 
9  88          298         False 
10 91          99          False 
11 99          106         False 
12 106         112         True 
13 106         109         True
```

I want to connect the source IDs of splitting events in a way that allows me to keep track of the history of each lineage.

For example, looking at row 13, the ideal value for an additional column "Lineage" would be something like:

```
   SOURCE_ID   TARGET_ID   Splitting_event  Lineage
13 106         109         True             "75.85.106"
```

So far, all my attempts at nested for loops and conditionals have failed and I don't know how to connect everything using the intermediate links (the ones where Splitting_event=False). I would be really grateful for any help with this!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What will be the value for 11th row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use df.apply functionality of pandas

```
def fn_apply(x):
    num = x.SOURCE_ID
    if x.SPLITTING_EVENT:
        lineage = [str(num)]
    else:
        lineage=[]
    while True:
        y = df.loc[df['TARGET_ID'] == num,:]
        if y.empty:
            break
        if y.SPLITTING_EVENT.values[0]:
            lineage.append(str(y.SOURCE_ID.values[0]))
        num = y.SOURCE_ID.values[0]
    if lineage:
        return ".".join(reversed(lineage))
    else:
        return None
df['lineage'] = df.apply(fn_apply, axis=1)
df
    SOURCE_ID   TARGET_ID   SPLITTING_EVENT     lineage
0   1           68          False               None
1   68          72          False               None
2   72          75          False               None
3   75          81          True                75
4   75          78          True                75
5   78          557         False               75
6   81          85          False               75
7   85          88          True                75.85
8   85          91          True                75.85
9   88          298         False               75.85
10  91          99          False               75.85
11  99          106         False               75.85
12  106         112         True                75.85.106
13  106         109         True                75.85.106
```

Let me know if this what you wanted

Comment: I did but my votes don't count yet (I just registered...) sorry :)